# Connecting a 22pin camera to RPi

Tags: camera

I have a 22pin camera I want to use with my RPi. I've seen many examples on-line and even [ready-to-buy adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076Q595HJ) of 15pin cameras to 22pin connectors for the RPi Zero. Below is a diagram of the adapter.

[image]

Can this be done the other way around? Connecting a 22pin camera with this adapter to a 15pin connector on any other RPi?

If not, how could I connect one then? Is there a way?

Comment: Is the camera known to work with the Raspberry Pi ? Does the GPU firmware contain a driver for your camera (actually there are only two supported models) ?

Comment: This is a camera taken from a [toy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQFLpC1UIcE), and afaik it's not any model *known to work* with the RPi. I don't have much information either regarding the actual camera model

Comment: Warning : Hardcore Linux kernel hacking ahead ! Unless you understand everything discussed here your chances are near zero : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=109137

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can only connect official camera modules to any Raspberry Pi. No other modules will work. This is both due to the fact that the camera is under direct control of the GPU firmware which only supports two different camera boards and that the camera port is configured for the Camera Serial Interface (CSI).

If you know the [MIPI CSI-2](https://www.mipi.org/specifications/csi-2) standard (legally available to paying members only) by heart and are an advanced C hacker, there might be an option of [reading data of other CSI sensors](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=109137). This approach means that you must run all mandatory image processing algorithms on the CPU which will likely impact performance, before you even get something resembling raw RGB or YUV data (*not* JPEG, not PNG and not h.264 either).

Comment: Raw RGB data wouldn't be that bad, I'm going to feed the camera into neural networks. But anyway, +1, good answer